# parsing JSON and appending in to list, what is best approach, Knockout.JS or JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I have came across one situation where I have to decide whether to use Knockout.JS or traditional Jquery way..

I have JSON with number of objects inside. I have to parse JSON and append values from objects in HTML Lists..

I have achieved this using JQuery `$.each()` and `parseJSON`.

I want to know if there is any difference (performance wise) if I use knockout.js compute over traditional Jquery parsing and using `$.each`?

Comment: it all depends ..if user has an option to interact with data change it add or delete it then use knockout.js if it is just for display what ever you have is fine. you dont need a knockout dependency

Comment: Performance questions are easy to answer. Write both variants, measure the difference. Apart from that the question "jQuery vs Knockout" is not about performance at all, you're missing the point.

Comment: User will not interact with the list, he will not manipulate or discard it. I guess JQuery approach is fine then.. No use of making things complicated for no reason :-)

Answer (score 0):

[knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) is not in a competition with [jquery](http://jquery.com/) they both working together as knockout depends on jQuery ..  So the right question is Why i should use [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) ? or What [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) 'll add to my project ?

you can start from [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) to know advantages from using library such [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

> Knockout is a JavaScript library that helps you to create rich,
>   responsive display and editor user interfaces with a clean underlying
>   data model. Any time you have sections of UI that update dynamically
>   (e.g., changing depending on the user’s actions or when an external
>   data source changes), KO can help you implement it more simply and
>   maintainably.

Answer (score 0):

The KnockoutJS library will help you with binding your UI lists to objects, but it has nothing to do with JSON parsing. I would recommend using KnockoutJS only if the responsiveness the app is your main requirement and your UI continuously updates.